# How to view a user's flag history?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

Is it possible or even allowed to view another user's flag history? If yes, how?

Comment: As a test, I just tried to view yours, but it gives the "Page Not Found" message. I assume that the history is only visible to moderators (or maybe people with sufficiently high rep). I'll let someone who actually knows the boundaries answer.

Comment: I think flag histories are supposed to be private (i.e. not even moderators can see them), but I could be wrong. Now, another interesting question: **why are you stalking other users' flag histories?**

Comment: @Cupcake: I was just curious, what if someone was a serial flagger (against one person)? How would a moderator find out if that is the case?

Comment: @Dennis nope, even Jon Skeet can't view our flag history, it's not rep-related. Only those with diamond can see it.

Comment: @Cupcake moderators can see them, see Tim's answer. :)

Comment: @Cupcake: Considering that we're the ones handling flags in the first place, if flag histories weren't visible to us we'd be pretty useless.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While this isn't personally identifiable information (as covered by our [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)), it's treated as non-public information. Only you and someone with moderator or above access can see your flagging history.

It's designed like this because flagging is something we *want* you to do, if you end up doing a horrible job of it, it's us (moderators and employees) that need to reach out to you. Opening up your flags opens you up to a potentially *huge* level of scrutiny, and possible revenge-like behavior from folks that had posts flagged by you. That's the sorts of things that make people want to *not* do something we really need them doing.

There is an exception to this, if you nominate yourself for moderator we *will* show the number of helpful flags you've raised (aggregate) and (shortly) the all-time number of flags you've raised. The change helps to prevent folks that haven't raised many helpful flags (due to not flagging much at all) from nominating *and then* rushing to get a bunch of helpful flags, often in the course doing it wrong.

We'd never reveal *what* you flagged, or how. *You* can reveal something you've flagged if you wish, perhaps to open a discussion about how a flag was handled or such, but basically every scenario in that realm has been played out here so it's not as common as it used to be.

Comment: Now I'm curious: What is "above moderator access"? Site owner? SE employee?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I think the answer to that question is classified as "above moderator access", so he might not know.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt It was "moderator or above" - community managers have some additional capabilities, and those with developer access have _many_ more capabilities.